# How to show filter at any particular column in material react table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-table, material-table, material-react-table

**When I click on filter option at First Name the filter feature also appears on Id, Last name and Full name. How can I just show filter to any specific column and rest remain as it is.**

[image]

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import MaterialReactTable from 'material-react-table';

function Table() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const columns = [
    { header: "id", accessorKey: "id" },
    { header: "First Name", accessorKey: "FirstName" },
    { header: "Last Name", accessorKey: "LastName" },
    { header: "Full Name", accessorKey: "FullName" },
  ];
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3030/getAllData")
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((resp) => {
        setData(resp["data"]);
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <MaterialReactTable
        data={data}
        columns={columns}    
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filterable property of the MaterialReactTable component to specify which columns should be filterable. You can pass an array of column accessorKey values to this property to enable filtering on those specific columns. Here's an example where "First Name" will be filterable:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import MaterialReactTable from 'material-react-table';

function Table() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const columns = [
    { header: "id", accessorKey: "id" },
    { header: "First Name", accessorKey: "FirstName", filterable: true },
    { header: "Last Name", accessorKey: "LastName" },
    { header: "Full Name", accessorKey: "FullName" },
  ];
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3030/getAllData")
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((resp) => {
        setData(resp["data"]);
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <MaterialReactTable
        data={data}
        columns={columns}    
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Table;
```

Comment: I did not find any property like "filterable" in MaterialReactTable, there is a property "enableColumnFilter" but I am not looking to disable the filter, I want to see filter feature on that particular column I have clicked not on all columns.